# App to App interfacing in Django

Tags: django, rest

We are developing a SaaS that uses a number of quite independent apps that are all currently in the same django project running on the same server.

We know that eventually some of the apps will be relocated to their own server primarily due to differences in server loads. We also believe some of the apps may become resources for new applications as well (the same app instances running in our SaaS).

We are at the point that we should go in an clean up cross app coupling and make rules about a common interface medium. My thoughts are that is should be a restful interface between all apps.

So: Is enforcing a restful interface across all apps a bad idea in the best case scenario for such an argument (all apps on different servers), and worst case scenario (all apps stay on the same server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take at look at [Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) for creating RESTful APIs in Django.